# Getting a sigseg fault when trying to modify an incrementing index in two separate arrays

Tags: arrays, c++11

So I'm trying to separate an array of char into blocks of 4 characters, keep track of whether the current block is even or odd, and rearrange them in increasing odd order and then increasing even order. I have an int variable to keep track of which index I'm at in the array and a for loop to determine if the current block is odd and if it is, put those characters into arrayOne, and if they're even put them into arrayTwo. At the end I would put arrayOne and arrayTwo together. However I think my incrementing idx variable in the loop checking if the current block is even is throwing a sigseg fault and i'm not sure why.

```
void unzip_file(const std::string& filename) {
ifstream file(filename, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
streampos sz = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
char* input = new char[sz];
file.read(input, sz);

char* arrayOne = new char[sz / 2];
char* arrayTwo = new char[sz / 2];
char* finalArray = new char[sz];
int eo = sz / 4;
int idx = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= eo; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            arrayOne[idx] = input[idx];
            idx++;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            arrayTwo[idx] = input[idx];
            idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the array that's passed into the function

```
H   W   e   o   l   r   l   l   o   d   ,   !
```

Comment: `arrayOne` is half size of `input`. Where should `input[sz-1]` go?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to the smaller `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` with the same index as the bigger `input` array. This will give a SEGV if `idx >= (sz / 2)` . Try using own indices for the smaller arrays.

```
// make input length multiple of 4
const char input[] = "H   W   e   o   l   r   l   l   o   d   ,   !   ";
const int sz = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);

// add one here if we want a c-string afterwarts (\0-terminated)
char* arrayOne = new char[(sz / 2) + 1];
char* arrayTwo = new char[(sz / 2) + 1];
char* finalArray = new char[sz];
int eo = sz / 4;
int idx = 0;

// keep different indices to arrayOne and arrayTwo
int idxOne = 0;
int idxTwo = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= eo; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            arrayOne[idxOne] = input[idx];
            idx++;
            // increment these seperately
            idxOne++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            arrayTwo[idxTwo] = input[idx];
            idx++;
            // increment these seperately
            idxTwo++;
        }
    }
}
// terminate to make a valid c-string
arrayOne[idxOne] = '\0';
arrayTwo[idxTwo] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", arrayOne);
printf("%s\n", arrayTwo);
```

**Note** If the size of the input size `sz` is not multiple of 4 you will miss the remaining characters in `input` (`sz / 4` rounds down).

**Note 2** If you want to `printf` the strings, the 0-termination is necessary (and a bigger array, see code comment).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the segmentation error but the contents of arrayOne is
    "H   e   l   l   o   ,   !"  and the contents of arrayTwo is
    "W   o   r   l   d   !   1"  Why am I getting an extra character at the end of each array and why is it a 1 in the second array? There isn't even a 1 in the input array.

Comment: What should the content of both array be after the loops?

Comment: arrayOne should be "H   e   l   l   o   ,   " and arrayTwo should be "W   o   r   l   d   !   ".

Comment: See updated answer. I have add spaces at the end of the input string, to make the length multiple of 4. And I 0-terminated the strings, to make them printable (unneecessary, if it does not have to be a c-string)